# Checkbox multiselect user interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I wrote a small multiple select interface in jQuery, and I'm looking for any feedback on code quality/usability.

It has to do the following:

1. When **check all** is checked, all boxes must become checked
2. When **check all** is unchecked, all boxes must become unchecked
3. When all boxes become checked the **check all** box must become checked
4. Then if one box is unchecked, the **check all** box must become unchecked
5. When any box is checked or unchecked a count must be updated, and the item `tr` must toggle a `selected` class.
6. If any checkbox is checked the tools button must appear
7. If no checkbox is checked the filters button must appear

```
var showToolbar = function() {
  $('[data-role="toolbar"]').show();
  $('[data-role="filters"]').hide();
};

var showFilters = function() {
  $('[data-role="toolbar"]').hide();
  $('[data-role="filters"]').show();
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('[data-select="items"]').on('click', function() {
    var checkAllBox = $(this),
        checkOneBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]');

    if ( checkAllBox.is(':checked') ) {
      checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
      showToolbar();
    } else {
      checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
      showFilters();
    }
  });

  $('[data-select="item"]').on('change', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this),
        tableRow = checkbox.parents('tr');

    if ( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {
      tableRow.addClass('selected');
    } else {
      tableRow.removeClass('selected');
    }

    var numberOfCheckedBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]:checked').length;

    if ( numberOfCheckedBoxes > 0 ) {
        showToolbar();
    } else {
        showFilters();
    }

    var numberOfUncheckedBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]').not(':checked').length;

    if ( numberOfUncheckedBoxes === 0 ) {
      $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', false);
    }

    var target = $('.items-selected'),
        html = numberOfCheckedBoxes + ' ';

    html += numberOfCheckedBoxes == 1 ?
              target.data('text-singular') : target.data('text-plural');
    target.html(html);
  });
});
```

```js
var showToolbar = function() {
  $('[data-role="toolbar"]').show();
  $('[data-role="filters"]').hide();
};

var showFilters = function() {
  $('[data-role="toolbar"]').hide();
  $('[data-role="filters"]').show();
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('[data-select="items"]').on('click', function() {
    var checkAllBox = $(this),
        checkOneBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]');

    if ( checkAllBox.is(':checked') ) {
      checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
      showToolbar();
    } else {
      checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
      showFilters();
    }
  });

  $('[data-select="item"]').on('change', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this),
        tableRow = checkbox.parents('tr');

    if ( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {
      tableRow.addClass('selected');
    } else {
      tableRow.removeClass('selected');
    }

    var numberOfCheckedBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]:checked').length;

    if ( numberOfCheckedBoxes > 0 ) {
     showToolbar();
    } else {
     showFilters();
    }

    var numberOfUncheckedBoxes = $('[data-select="item"]').not(':checked').length;

    if ( numberOfUncheckedBoxes === 0 ) {
      $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', false);
    }

    var target = $('.items-selected'),
        html = numberOfCheckedBoxes + ' ';

    html += numberOfCheckedBoxes == 1 ? target.data('text-singular') : target.data('text-plural');
    target.html(html);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.toolbar {
  display: none;
}
tr.selected > td {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="toolbar" data-role="toolbar">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Tools</a>
    </div>
    <div class="filters" data-role="filters">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Filters</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="items-selected" data-text-singular="item selected" data-text-plural="items selected">0 items selected</div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="items">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Hummus
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Beirut
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Tabouleh
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Sidon
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Fatouch Salad
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-select="item">
      </td>
      <td>
        Lebanon
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this:

> ```
> if ( numberOfUncheckedBoxes === 0 ) {
>   $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', true);
> } else {
>   $('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', false);
> }
> ```

Like this:

```
$('[data-select="items"]').prop('checked', numberOfUncheckedBoxes === 0);
```

Similarly, if you add this helper function:

```
var showOrHideToolbar = function(show) {
  if (show) {
    showToolbar();
  } else {
    showFilters();
  }
}
```

Then you could simplify this:

> ```
> if ( checkAllBox.is(':checked') ) {
>   checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
>   showToolbar();
> } else {
>   checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
>   showFilters();
> }
> ```

Like this:

```
var checkAllChecked = checkAllBox.is(':checked');
checkOneBoxes.prop('checked', checkAllChecked).trigger('change');
showOrHideToolbar(checkAllChecked);
```

And this one:

> ```
> if ( numberOfCheckedBoxes > 0 ) {
>     showToolbar();
> } else {
>     showFilters();
> }
> ```

Like this:

```
showOrHideToolbar(numberOfCheckedBoxes > 0);
```

Comment: Great review. Thanks. One thing that bothers about this, coming from a Ruby background, is that JavaScript seems to float around. By that I mean it's not encapsulated in a class. So my project ends up having several files of such code floating around... it seems "messy"

Comment: To avoid JavaScript code floating around, look into frameworks like BackboneJS and AngularJS